# Message sent successfully: Error: operation has timed out at Timeout._onTimeout

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

```
 io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log("soket")
    socket.on("addnewuser", (id) => {
      if (!onlineuser[id]) {
        onlineuser[id] = socket.id; // Add the user to the onlineUsers object
      }

      console.log("onlineuser", onlineuser)
    })
    // Server-side code
    socket.on("newmsg", (data) => {
      const recipientId = data[0].recipientId;
      const msg = data[0].message;

      const fetchUser = onlineuser[recipientId];

      console.log("Recipient ID:", recipientId);
      console.log("Fetch User Socket ID:", fetchUser);
      console.log("Message Data:", data);

      if (fetchUser) {
        io.to(fetchUser).emit("getmsg", msg, (response) => {
          if (response.error) {
            console.log("Message delivery failed:", response.error);
          } else {
            console.log("Message sent successfully:", response);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Recipient socket not found.");
        // Handle the case where the recipient is not online
      }
    });
```

stuck on this error. i do not understand whats happening. when i try to send one to one msg in socket this happens